# Spring Data Mongodb starter only creates localhost cluster

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to create a simple Spring Boot ReST app that uses spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb to auto create the connection, repository. The mongo database I am attempting to connect to is in Mongo Atlas on Azure. Alas no matter what I specify in spring.data.mongodb.uri= it only tries to connect to localhost. I don't have Mongo running locally so of course the connection fails. That one param is all there is in my properties file and I know the connect string is correct but I can connect using the same string from a simple java app.

What do I need to to be able to connect to Atlas using the starter?

```
2021-08-21 14:51:31.183  INFO 24000 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
```

Comment: where did you define atlas uri ? please check on profile which is using by spring boot application.

Comment: The uri is defined in application.properties.

Comment: please add what is the property you are adding and URI. (well atleast dummy URI )